# Output rows with values that are close to input value

Tags: python, pandas

How can I output all rows in a dataframe with values close to numbers I input?

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'A':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
        'B':[11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A', 'B'])
```

So a function like `nearest_values(df, A, B)` which outputs rows within 2 of the specified inputs. If I input `nearest_values(df 5, 15)` it would return rows:

```
|     A    |     B    |
| -------- | -------- |
| 3        | 13       |
| 4        | 14       |
| 5        | 15       |
| 6        | 16       |
| 7        | 17       |
```

Comment: Determining whether two values are "close" is covered in many places.  Filtering a data frame on a given condition is covered in any PANDAS tutorial.  How are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to subtract the values from the DataFrame and compare to a tolerance:

```
def nearest_values(df, A, B, tolerance=2):
    return df[(abs(df - [A, B]) <= tolerance).all(axis=1)]
```

(This can also be for n columns):

```
def nearest_values(df, *cols, tolerance=2):
    return df[(abs(df - cols) <= tolerance).all(axis=1)]
```

`nearest_values(df, 5, 15)`:

```
   A   B
2  3  13
3  4  14
4  5  15
5  6  16
6  7  17
```

If any value in the row matching the tolerance is acceptable, change `all` to `any`.

---

Explanation:

```
df - [A, B]
```

Uses subtraction to "compare" the search values against the DataFrame:

```
   A  B
0 -4 -4
1 -3 -3
2 -2 -2
3 -1 -1
4  0  0
5  1  1
6  2  2
7  3  3
8  4  4
9  5  5
```

`abs` is applied to convert all negative values to positive values, then a comparison is done against the tolerance:

```
abs(df - [A, B]) <= tolerance
```

```
       A      B
0  False  False
1  False  False
2   True   True
3   True   True
4   True   True
5   True   True
6   True   True
7  False  False
8  False  False
9  False  False
```

Then an evaluation can be done about the truthfulness of a given row. In this case `all(axis=1)` but `any(axis=1)` is also an option:

```
(abs(df - [A, B]) <= tolerance).all(axis=1)
```

```
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
5     True
6     True
7    False
8    False
9    False
dtype: bool
```

This can be used as an index to select the desired rows:

---

Complete Working Example

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
        'B': [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A', 'B'])


def nearest_values(df, *cols, tolerance=2):
    return df[(abs(df - cols) <= tolerance).all(axis=1)]


print(nearest_values(df, 5, 15))
```